# Adding left and right full swipe gesture on listview using xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

[image]Currently i have a listview which stores the medications of my users, i want to implement a swipe gesture so that the user can simply swipe left or right to tell if the medication has been taken or not taken.

Is there a way to add a left and right full swipe gesture in a listview just like the way that apple has implemented in their mail.

Comment: Did you check this official document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note:it cannot achieved moved item follow with fingertip, but could achieved left and right gestures
First, you should build swipe compoment using gesture

SwipeGestureGrid.cs

```
public class SwipeGestureGrid : Grid
{
    #region Private Member
    private double _gestureX { get; set; }
    private double _gestureY { get; set; }
    private bool IsSwipe { get; set; }
    #endregion
    #region Public Member
    #region Events
    #region Tapped
    public event EventHandler Tapped;
    protected void OnTapped(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Tapped != null)
            Tapped(this, e);
    }
    #endregion
    #region SwipeUP
    public event EventHandler SwipeUP;
    protected void OnSwipeUP(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (SwipeUP != null)
            SwipeUP(this, e);
    }
    #endregion
    #region SwipeDown
    public event EventHandler SwipeDown;
    protected void OnSwipeDown(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (SwipeDown != null)
            SwipeDown(this, e);
    }
    #endregion
    #region SwipeRight
    public event EventHandler SwipeRight;
    protected void OnSwipeRight(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (SwipeRight != null)
            SwipeRight(this, e);
    }
    #endregion
    #region SwipeLeft
    public event EventHandler SwipeLeft;
    protected void OnSwipeLeft(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (SwipeLeft != null)
            SwipeLeft(this, e);
    }
    #endregion
    #endregion
    public double Height
    {
        get
        {
            return HeightRequest;
        }
        set
        {
            HeightRequest = value;
        }
    }
    public double Width
    {
        get
        {
            return WidthRequest;
        }
        set
        {
            WidthRequest = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion
    public SwipeGestureGrid()
    {
        PanGestureRecognizer panGesture = new PanGestureRecognizer();
        panGesture.PanUpdated += PanGesture_PanUpdated;

        TapGestureRecognizer tapGesture = new TapGestureRecognizer();
        tapGesture.Tapped += TapGesture_Tapped;

        GestureRecognizers.Add(panGesture);
        GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGesture);
    }

    private void TapGesture_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!IsSwipe)
                OnTapped(null);

            IsSwipe = false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }

    private void PanGesture_PanUpdated(object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            switch (e.StatusType)
            {
                case GestureStatus.Running:
                    {
                        _gestureX = e.TotalX;
                        _gestureY = e.TotalY;
                    }
                    break;
                case GestureStatus.Completed:
                    {
                        IsSwipe = true;
                        //Debug.WriteLine("{0}  {1}", _gestureX, _gestureY);
                        if (Math.Abs(_gestureX) > Math.Abs(_gestureY))
                        {
                            if (_gestureX > 0)
                            {
                                OnSwipeRight(null);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                OnSwipeLeft(null);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (_gestureY > 0)
                            {
                                OnSwipeDown(null);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                OnSwipeUP(null);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Next using datatemplate in listview andattach event for GesturecompomentPage.cs

```
   ListView lsvData = new ListView()
    {
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
        BackgroundColor = Color.White,
        HasUnevenRows = true,
    };
    List<string> lstData = new List<string>();
    public Pages()
    {
        #region DataTemplate
        DataTemplate ListDataTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
        {
            #region DataArea of Template
            SwipeGestureGrid gridData = new SwipeGestureGrid()
            {
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                HeightRequest = 60,
                RowDefinitions =
                    {
                        new RowDefinition { },
                    },
                ColumnDefinitions =
                    {
                        new ColumnDefinition { },
                    }
            };
            #endregion
            #region Base of Template
            Grid gridBase = new Grid()
            {
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                HeightRequest = 60,
                RowDefinitions =
                {
                    new RowDefinition { },
                },
                ColumnDefinitions =
                {
                    new ColumnDefinition { },                                                   
                //Put Cells Data here
                    new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(0, 
                GridUnitType.Absolute)},   //Button for Cells here
                },
            };
            #endregion
            Label lblText = new Label
            {
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold,
                VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.End,
                TextColor = Color.Black,
                BackgroundColor = Color.Silver,
                LineBreakMode = LineBreakMode.TailTruncation,
                FontSize = 18,
            };
            lblText.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, ".");

            ImageButton btnCellDelete = new ImageButton() { Source = "Delete" };

            gridData.Children.Add(lblText, 0, 0);

            gridBase.Children.Add(gridData, 0, 0);
            gridBase.Children.Add(btnCellDelete, 1, 0);

            gridData.SwipeLeft += GridTemplate_SwipeLeft;
            gridData.SwipeRight += GridTemplate_SwipeRight; ;
            gridData.Tapped += GridTemplate_Tapped; ;
            btnCellDelete.Clicked += BtnCellDelete_Clicked; ;

            return new ViewCell
            {
                View = gridBase,
                Height = 60,
            };
        });

        #endregion
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            lstData.Add(i.ToString());
        }
        lsvData.ItemTemplate = ListDataTemplate;
        lsvData.ItemsSource = lstData;
        Content = lsvData;
    }
```

Add the event.SwipeLeft to show DeleteButton

```
   private void GridTemplate_SwipeLeft(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (sender is SwipeGestureGrid)
        {
            var templateGrid = ((SwipeGestureGrid)sender).Parent;
            if (templateGrid != null && templateGrid is Grid)
            {
                var CellTemplateGrid = (Grid)templateGrid;
                CellTemplateGrid.ColumnDefinitions[1].Width = new GridLength(60, GridUnitType.Absolute);
            }
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

swiperight to hide delete button

```
private void GridTemplate_SwipeRight(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (sender is SwipeGestureGrid)
        {
            var templateGrid = ((SwipeGestureGrid)sender).Parent;
            if (templateGrid != null && templateGrid is Grid)
            {
                var CellTemplateGrid = (Grid)templateGrid;
                CellTemplateGrid.ColumnDefinitions[1].Width = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Absolute);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Delete button click event

```
 private void BtnCellDelete_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (sender is ImageButton)
        {
            var templateGrid = ((ImageButton)sender);
            //templateGrid.Parent = gridBase
            //templateGrid.Parent.Parent = cell
            if (templateGrid.Parent != null && templateGrid.Parent.Parent != null && templateGrid.Parent.Parent.BindingContext != null && templateGrid.Parent.Parent.BindingContext is string)
            {
                var deletedate = templateGrid.Parent.Parent.BindingContext as string;
                lstData.RemoveAll(f => f == deletedate);
                lsvData.ItemsSource = null;
                lsvData.ItemsSource = lstData;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

There is all code.
https://github.com/act70255/ListViewSwipeGesture

Comment: Are there any updates for this issue? If the reply is helpful, please try to mark it as an answer,  it will help others who have similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

I will create a listview with a custom cells

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-cell-appearance

and i add swipe left and right gestures on a grid inside to a ViewCell

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/swipe

on left swipe i expand with animation something like a grid column where on start the width is 0 and after swap animated to some width. Same with right swipe.

Check for the animation the OnExpandExchange() method from here
  https://github.com/xamarinium/FlippingAndResizableUI/blob/master/FlippingAndResizableView/BitcoinView.xaml.cs